# JSON URL not working with Parameters

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have written the following code to read a JSON document from an external URL. This worked fine when the URL was the following:

```
 http://localhost/EWSimpleWebAPI/odata/Users?
```

But NOT when I modified the URL as the following:

```
http://localhost/EWSimpleWebAPI/odata/Users?$filter=USER_NAME%20eq%20%27corpnet\anuwlk%27&$select=PROFILE
```

**Javascript**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "http://localhost/EWSimpleWebAPI/odata/Users?$filter=USER_NAME%20eq%20%27corpnet\anuwlk%27&$select=PROFILE";

xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    errorAlert("Status OKAY");
  } else{
    errorAlert("Status Not OKAY")
  }
}

xmlhttp.send();
```

I'm retrieving the JSON Document thru a Web API using OData. OData accepts parameters in the URL and it worked fine in POSTMAN. I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'm not sure if it supports this URL with Parameters.

Comment: Your url has an unescaped control character `\a`, should be `\\a`. I've voted to close the question due to the problem being a typo.

Comment: Thanks, your comment solved my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use some function ( `encodeURIComponent(str)` and `encodeURI(str)` come to mind) to encode the parameters correctly.

As wOxxOm commented, your issue seems that one of the parameter has an unescaped character `\`.

Comment: [See this answer for clearness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)